# Why can't i use switch statement to switch between views in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

i used this turtorial: http://www.paulusworld.com/technical/android-navigationdrawer-sliding-tabs#comment-2793

to get a swipe view alongside my navigation drawer, but i can't quite figure out how to change the view

in the onCreateView i'm trying to do it with a switch statement but it says "method is not overwriting method from it's superclass

code for fragment:

```
public class StepFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = StepFragment.class.getSimpleName();
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;


public static StepFragment newInstance() {
    return new StepFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step_fragment, container, false);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getChildFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    return v;
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new TabbedContentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TabbedContentFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.step_title1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.step_title2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.step_title3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class TabbedContentFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public TabbedContentFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState,int position) {

        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step,
                container, false);

        View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step1,
                container, false);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return view1;
            case 1:
                return view2;

        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onCreateView is passing four arguments, the superclass method only takes 3.  You need to remove the position arg.

Use the args Bundle that you're setting in getItem() to pass the position.  In onCreateView(), get those args and pull the position from that Bundle.

EDIT:

Here's your getItem():

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new TabbedContentFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(TabbedContentFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Since your switch statement in onCreateView is looking for a 0 or 1, go ahead and remove the "+ 1" from args.putInt():

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new TabbedContentFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(TabbedContentFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Now, in your fragment, you need to get the args and get the position from that:

```
public static class TabbedContentFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public TabbedContentFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 0);

        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step,
                container, false);

        View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step1,
                container, false);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return view1;
            case 1:
                return view2;

        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: okay, i get what you're saying, i'm just not entirely sure how to do it, do you think you could help me out with some code? I tried putting ARG_SECTION_NUMBER into the switch statement, but it said it was a string. Appreciate the help :)